# Memory compactor in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures

I have a program that simulates best-fit memory management.
Basically, while there are available holes in the holes list, large enough for a process we are trying to allocate, processes are allocated and added to the process list. However, eventually, we get to a point where holes become very fragmented and we need to perform compaction.

The easiest way to do this, is obviously to create a new list and add all the processes in sequential order. However, that is not very realistic, since in real world, you wouldn't have space to move things to and create a new list.

Can you think of a way to push all the processes to one end of memory and free space to the other? Basically it is set up like this array of holes (holes are structs that contain starting index and size) and an array of processes (processes are also structs that contain process id, starting index and size).

Comment: You make no mention of the OS you are running on - so basically your program has no real memory addresses so it has no real holes? Do you have really have these holes or not? So what OS?

Comment: Please give us more context about your question, in particular OS and granularity of the allocations. If you are e.g talking about user space (= virtual memory) on a linux system, my guess would be that all your question doesn't make much sense. The continuity of address space on such a system is only a fiction, behind the scenes the OS has a mapping function of memory pages to physical memory that is not at all linear. Reorgenizing virtual memory makes not much sense.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking here. You are trying to implement the behavior of most VMM's in user space? It looks like you're looking at this as a bin packing problem, which is why I'm a little confused on precisely what you're doing.

Comment: Is it right to assume we're dealing with physical memory and processes are relocated (in the sense of patching addresses) when they are moved from one place to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shuffle the the allocated memory to the end of available memory one after another.

Pseudocode:

```
sort procs by start_index                           (descending)
avail_end = END_OF_MEM - p[0].size                  (adjust alignment)

for p in procs

     memmove( avail_end, p.start_index , p.size )
     avail_end = avail_end  - p.size
```

this should lead to one free memory block at the beginning of available memory. You could also stop this function after one region has moved (after a time threshold has reached) and continue later (By testing whter there is a gap beetween subsequent process alocated regions, to skip unneccesary moves).

Answer (score 1):

If the array of holes is sorted on starting index, you could iterate over the array and take two holes and move the memory chunk in between to the start index of the first hole.

---

**Further explanation:**

Each hole has a starting index and an ending index equal to `start_index + size`.
By comparing the ending index of the first hole to the starting index of the second, you get the size of the memory chunk in between. Then you can do a [memmove](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memmove.3.html) of the memory chunk to the first starting index.

Answer (score 0):

When freeing a memory (and creating a hole), do you already merge it with adjacent holes? Otherwise that is a good idea to lessen fragmentation.